# how to change order title

Tags: magento2, orders

i want to change order title in the phtml file, but I can't find it ever in vendor, can anyone help me please ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is coming from the **info.php** file. I would recommend to override this file and then make changes in it.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/info.php

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Order # %1', $this->getOrder()->getRealOrderId()));
        $infoBlock = $this->paymentHelper->getInfoBlock($this->getOrder()->getPayment(), $this->getLayout());
        $this->setChild('payment_info', $infoBlock);
    }
```

Comment: It also may be easier to retranslate the page title in the theme.